# Unable to access service or repository with AbstractRoutingDataSource using jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a dynamic database spring boot application. who can use the multiple databases at run time.

The problem is that I can not use service or repository while accessing the table data.

Below is my Config Class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class 
})
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo"})

public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
        private Environment env;

    @Resource
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;

    @Bean 
    XmlConverter xmlConverter(){
        XmlConverter xmlConverter = new XmlConverter();
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(castorMarshaller());
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(castorMarshaller());
        return xmlConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CastorMarshaller castorMarshaller(){
        CastorMarshaller castorMarshaller = new CastorMarshaller();
        castorMarshaller.setMappingLocation(appContext.getResource("classpath:mapping.xml"));
        return castorMarshaller;
    }


     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {


        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new DBRoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object,Object>  targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_AUSTRIA,lending_dataSource_9());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_BELGIUM,lending_dataSource_2());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_BRAZIL,lending_dataSource_11());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_CHILE,lending_dataSource_12());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_COLOMBIA,lending_dataSource_13());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_FRANCE,lending_dataSource_7());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_GERMANY,lending_dataSource_8());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_ITALY,lending_dataSource_1());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_MEXICO,lending_dataSource_14());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_NETHERLAND,lending_dataSource_3());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_SWISS,lending_dataSource_10());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.COLL_UK,lending_dataSource_4());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_BRAZIL,css_dataSource_11());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_CHILE,css_dataSource_12());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_COLOMBIA,css_dataSource_13());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_FRANCE,css_dataSource_7());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_GERMANY,css_dataSource_8());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_ITALY,css_dataSource_1());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_MEXICO,css_dataSource_14());
        targetDataSources.put(DBContextHolder.DBName.CSS_UK,css_dataSource_4());
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        //dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(lending_dataSource_11());
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return dataSource;
    }   


     public DataSource lending_dataSource_1() {
       DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_ITALY.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_ITALY.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_ITALY.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_ITALY.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_2() {
       DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BELGIUM.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BELGIUM.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BELGIUM.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BELGIUM.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_3() {
       DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_NETHERLAND.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_NETHERLAND.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_NETHERLAND.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_NETHERLAND.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }

    public DataSource lending_dataSource_4() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_UK.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_UK.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_UK.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_UK.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }



    public DataSource lending_dataSource_7() {
       DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_FRANCE.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_FRANCE.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_FRANCE.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_FRANCE.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_8() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_GERMANY.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_GERMANY.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_GERMANY.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_GERMANY.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    public DataSource lending_dataSource_9() {
       DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_AUSTRIA.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_AUSTRIA.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_AUSTRIA.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_AUSTRIA.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_10() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_SWISS.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_SWISS.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_SWISS.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_SWISS.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    public DataSource lending_dataSource_11() {

    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_12() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_CHILE.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_CHILE.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_CHILE.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_CHILE.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_13() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_COLOMBIA.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_COLOMBIA.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_COLOMBIA.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_COLOMBIA.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource lending_dataSource_14() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_MEXICO.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_MEXICO.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_MEXICO.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_MEXICO.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource css_dataSource_1() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource css_dataSource_4() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource css_dataSource_8() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }



    public DataSource css_dataSource_7() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource css_dataSource_11() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }



    public DataSource css_dataSource_12() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }


    public DataSource css_dataSource_13() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }



    public DataSource css_dataSource_14() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.password"));
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("COLL_BRAZIL.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

    }


    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();

        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Below is DBContextHolder  Class:

```
public class DBContextHolder {
    public enum DBName {
        CSS_ITALY,
        CSS_UK,
        CSS_COLOMBIA,
        CSS_BRAZIL,
        CSS_GERMANY,
        CSS_FRANCE,
        CSS_CHILE,
        CSS_MEXICO,
        COLL_ITALY,
        COLL_UK,
        COLL_BELGIUM,
        COLL_AUSTRIA,
        COLL_NETHERLAND,
        COLL_SWISS,
        COLL_GERMANY,
        COLL_FRANCE,
        COLL_COLOMBIA,
        COLL_BRAZIL,
        COLL_CHILE,
        COLL_MEXICO

    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<DBName> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<DBName>();
    private static DBName type = null;

    public static void setDBName(DBName dbName) {
        Assert.notNull(dbName, "customerType cannot be null");
        contextHolder.set(dbName);
        type = dbName;
        contextHolder.set(type);
    }

    public static DBName getDBName() {
        //return type;
        return (DBName) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDBName() {
        type = null;
        contextHolder.remove();
    }

}
```

Below is DBRoutingDataSource Class:

```
public class DBRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DBContextHolder.getDBName();
    }
}
```

Below is Service Class:

```
public interface DBService {

        public String getDBData(String sql);


}
```

Below is Service Class:

```
@Service("DBService")
public class DBServiceImpl  implements DBService{

    @Autowired
    DBDao DBDao;    




    @Override
    public String getDBData(String sql) {
       return  DBDao.getDBData(sql);
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Below is Repository Class:

```
public interface DBDao {

    public String getDBData(String sql);

}
```

Below is Repository Class:

```
@Component
@Repository
@Transactional
@Qualifier("DBDao")
public class DBDaoImpl  implements DBDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @Override
    public String getDBData(String sql) {

        try {


            if (jdbcTemplate.getDataSource() instanceof org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) {
                org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tcDataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                // System.out.println("Schema: " + jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getSchema());
                System.out.println("Schema: "+tcDataSource.getUrl());
                System.out.println("Schema: "+tcDataSource.getUsername());

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       // System.out.println("sql: " + sql);
        return (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{}, String.class);

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Below is UtilHelper Class which used Service or Repository that causing the issue:

```
 public class UtilHelper {


           @Resource(name="DBService")
            private DBService DBService;



    public HashMap<String,String> getData(String countryName,String module, HashMap queryData)
        {


            Iterator itr = queryData.entrySet().iterator();

            String query=null;

                while(itr.hasNext())        
                {
                    Map.Entry qEntry = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
                    query = (String)qEntry.getValue();
                   // log.debug("Query is -->"+query);
                    try
                    {
                        if(module.equals("COLL")){
                            if(countryName.equals("Brazil")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_BRAZIL);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Italy")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_ITALY);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Belgium")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_BELGIUM);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Netherlands")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_NETHERLAND);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("United Kingdom")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_UK);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("France")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_FRANCE);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Germany")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_GERMANY);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Austria")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_AUSTRIA);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Switzerland")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_SWISS);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Chile")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_CHILE);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Colombia")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.COLL_COLOMBIA);
                            }

                        }else if(module.equals("CSS")){
                            if(countryName.equals("BRAZIL_CSS")) {
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_BRAZIL);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("UK_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_UK);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Germany_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_GERMANY);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Chile_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_CHILE);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Colombia_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_COLOMBIA);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("Italy_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_ITALY);
                            }else if(countryName.equals("France_CSS")){
                                DBContextHolder.setDBName(DBName.CSS_FRANCE);

                            }


                        }


                       //System.out.println("DBSERVICD Query: "+(query));
                       //System.out.println("DBSERVICD Country: "+(countryName));
                       //System.out.println("DBSERVICD Module: "+(module));
                        System.out.println("DBSERVICD DATA: "+DBService.getDBData(query));
                        queryData.put(qEntry.getKey(),DBService.getDBData(query));

                    }
                    catch(Exception sqle)
                    {

                        String error = "Error: "+sqle.getMessage()+"Query: "+query+"\n CONTINUE???";
                        sqle.printStackTrace();
                        //connIssuePop(error);
                        queryData.put(qEntry.getKey(),"No Data");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            return queryData;
        }

    }
```

In the above code I can not access service (DBService) in the application.
Everytime it is null. But when i tried to access it with

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        DBService DBService = (DBService) context.getBean("DBService");
```

it is working fine with multiple databases but it takes lots of time to initialize all the beans register the beans and use shutdown hook. I don't want to use this, But unable to use only service or repository in the application because every time its value is null.

Here is my SpringBootApplication Class where I use the UtilHelper Class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMarshallingApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Resource
    XmlConverter xmlConverter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMarshallingApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        final String queriesCollxmlFile = "QueriesColl.xml";
        final String dbInfoCollxmlFile = "dbInfoColl.xml";
        final String queriesCSSxmlFile = "QueriesCSS.xml";
        final String dbInfoCSSxmlFile = "dbInfoCSS.xml";
        HashMap<String,HashMap> listMap=new HashMap<String,HashMap>();
        System.out.println("Convert Xml to Customer Object!");

        System.out.println("dbInfoColl.xml>>>>>>>>>>>>!");
        dbInfo dbInfoColl = (dbInfo) xmlConverter.convertFromXMLToObject(dbInfoCollxmlFile);
        Queries cust2 = (Queries) xmlConverter.convertFromXMLToObject(queriesCollxmlFile);
        System.out.println(dbInfoColl.getCountry().size());
                   for (country country : dbInfoColl.getCountry()) {

            UtilHelper util=new UtilHelper();
            HashMap queryData= util.genQueries(country, cust2.getQuery());
           // util.getData(dbInfoCSSxmlFile, dbInfoCSSxmlFile, queryData);
            HashMap data =util.getData(country.getCountryName(),"COLL",queryData);
            listMap.put(country.getCountryName(),data);
       //     System.out.println(country.toString());
        }



        for (Query query : cust2.getQuery()) {
            System.out.print(query.getQueryValue()+"     ");
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : listMap.entrySet()) {
            String countryName = entry.getKey();
            HashMap <String,String> value = entry.getValue();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : value.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry1.getKey();
                String value1 = entry1.getValue();
                System.out.print(key+":"+value1+"     ");
            }
            System.out.println("  ");
        }


        for (Query query : cust2.getQuery()) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : listMap.entrySet()) {
            String countryName = entry.getKey();
            HashMap <String,String> value = entry.getValue();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : value.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry1.getKey();
                String value1 = entry1.getValue();

                if(query.getQueryValue().trim().toUpperCase().equals(key.toString().trim().toUpperCase()))
                    {
                         System.out.print(key+":"+value1+"     ");
                    }


            }
            System.out.println("  ");
        }

        }     

        System.out.println("QueriesColl.xml>>>>>>>>>>>>!");

        System.out.println(cust2.getQuery().size());

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `UtilHelper` class is not a bean, therefore it is not having any of it's dependencies injected. You did not show where you're using this class, so hard to tell how to fix it better.

Comment: @Strelok : I have added springboot application class where i used UtilHelper. Now can you suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Strelok: you made my day. Thanks a lot.Its working fine now.